# Save Array Key and Value at the same time in Database with MSSQL and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I want to save key  and value of an array inside a foreach loop in a database with mssql and php.

Here is my array, i encoded it on json ($myArr):

```
{
  "UPC-A": "55055",
  "EAN-13": "7077707",
  "UPC": "0940",
  "GTIN": "009642",
  "GTIN-14": "566642"
}
```

This is my code:

```
foreach($myArr as $key => $val){
   $insert = "Insert Into tbl (barcodeType,barcode) Values ($key, $val)"
   $stmtBar = $db->prepare($insertBarcode);  
   $stmtBar->execute();
   //what is the best approach for this???    
}
```

The output should be like this when encode in json from database:

```
{
"barcodeType": "UPC-A",
"barcode": "55055"
},
{
"barcodeType": "EAN-13",
"barcode": "7077707"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this -

```
<?php

$a = '{
  "UPC-A": "55055",
  "EAN-13": "7077707",
  "UPC": "0940",
  "GTIN": "009642",
  "GTIN-14": "566642"
}';

$myArr = json_decode($a);
$values = '';
foreach($myArr as $key => $val){
   $values .= "(".$key.",".$val."),";
}
$insert = "Insert Into tbl (barcodeType,barcode) Values ".rtrim($values,',');
$stmtBar = $db->prepare($insert);
$stmtBar->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{
  "UPC-A": "55055",
  "EAN-13": "7077707",
  "UPC": "0940",
  "GTIN": "009642",
  "GTIN-14": "566642"
}';

$myArr = json_decode($jsonData);
foreach($myArr as $key => $val){
   $insert = "Insert Into tbl (barcodeType,barcode) Values ($key, $val)"
   $stmtBar = $db->prepare($insertBarcode);  
   $stmtBar->execute();
}
$selectStmt = "select * from tbl";
$jsonArray = array();
foreach ($db->query($selectStmt) as $results)
{
   $jsonArray[] = array('barcodeType' => $results['barcodeType'],'barcode' => $results['barcode']);
}
$result = json_encode($jsonArray,true);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: I need it first to insert it in the database from the first json encode format

Comment: I have added for insert also